# ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons. How can I edit php.ini file in cPanel?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I am getting error "ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons ..." in a Wordpress website. How can I solve this?
I have access to cPanel but I can't find php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel 11 You can use search bar in the top for search what you need.
this is example:
[image]

Comment: I searched in cPanel and file manager but couldn't find the file

Comment: @IhtishamKhan what your cpanel version? I checked on Cpanel11 version 88.0.9. https://imgur.com/Wc743QC

Comment: I have cPanel 88.0.9

Comment: I do have MultiPHP manager but cannot access php.ini file from here

Comment: oh. maybe your account does not have permission for this action. try contact support for this problem